# Deploying SSTP VPN on Windows 2012 - How to route packets to other servers?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, routing, windows-server-2012, sstp

I've finally managed to deploy an SSTP VPN between my Windows 2012 (non R2) server and Windows 7 client. It's amazing how much easier it work with a real certificate and avoiding the self-signed debacle. Anyway, my client can ping the VPN server and the VPN server can ping it, but I can't ping any of the other machines on the domain, specifically the domain controller.

What do I need to do to make the machine able to access the other servers? Currently it has the *Remote Access: DirectAccess and VPN* role installed. I have **not** installed the *Network Policy and Access Services* nor the *Remote Access: Routing* roles. I'm not sure if they're needed, but I did see them being installed in the dozens of tutorials I looked at online.

I'm thinking the NPS may be needed to make the routing work, but I don't know how to proceeed. I've spent the last three weeks trying to make this work, so I kind of want to hold on to what I've managed to get working so far without exploring on my own. Recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How many clients do you have? Also, what kind of connection did you configure? Poin-to-point or point-to-network(site)? I think, you have point-to-point, so you simply establish connection between 2 comps and thats why you cant see the rest computers on the server side. If you could have point-to-site connection, then you could see the whole server's network, without any routing though.

Comment: Right now I just have the one server and one client, but in the future I'll be adding more clients. I guess technically it is a point-to-point, but Idk how make it point-to-site. The problem is that the servers are on and AWS VPC, so Idk how a point-to-site can be made on it...

Comment: Actually, especially for Azure there are a ton of information with step by step configs. How about this?-> https://www.google.com/search?q=sstp+vpn+azure+poiunt-to-site&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#newwindow=1&q=sstp+vpn+azure+point-to-site

Comment: Just realized you use Amazon, anyway, have a look at the configs for Azure and see if you can apply it for Amazon. Though, I didn't work with Amazon... can't give any helpful comments. But the thing is, look for point-to-site connection not the routing thing. Hope it helps you